# protocol implementation in VEINS

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am successfully able to establish a connection between Omnet++ and SUMO using the sumo-launchd.py and am able to track the vehicles.

**The main problem is that I am not able to understand which routing protocol is used and where it is written in the VEINS package.
This is my main concern because I cannot implement my own proposed routing algorithm unless I understand the protocol already existing.**

Hope that I will get some sort of assistance

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the demo application which is shipped with Veins and how to start building your own scenario and applications please read the following posts:

- [What exactly does handleParkingUpdate() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372048/what-exactly-does-handleparkingupdate-do/43430215#43430215)
- [Building my own veins scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609196/building-my-own-veins-scenario/46647841#46647841)
- [Regarding Dynamic Routing in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781147/regarding-dynamic-routing-in-veins/42781561#42781561)
- [what policy is based vehicle rerouting in case of accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373278/what-policy-is-based-vehicle-rerouting-in-case-of-accident)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am still not able to get how to implement a routing protocol in VEINS. For example, how can I implement the GPSR protocol? Where should i write the code for the protocol in VEINS?

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390016/how-to-getting-start-to-build-a-veins-application tells you, start with MyVeinsApp and add the functionality of your algorithm there.