# VEINS/PLEXE simulator: how to use self-defined application

Tags: veins, plexe, plexe-veins

Currently, I am working on simulating platoons based on ETSI G5 standards in Europe. The framework I am using is PLEXE (an extension of VEINS) on Ubuntu 20.04 (VMWare).

According to [this pose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390016/how-to-get-start-to-build-a-veins-application/46400589#46400589), after defining my application (I assume .cc/.h files in src/plexe or src/veins), I should modify the omnetpp.ini to use my application. I need to define my application because as far as I know, PLEXE (VEINS) supports the US standard (WAVE). However, I am unclear on how (where) the .cc/.h files link with the simulation. Here are my questions:

- How is my defined application linked with the simulation? In other words, how to modify omnetpp.ini to use my application?
- Another small question is that another extension of VEINS that supports ETSI G5 is Artery which has a submodule called Vanetza. Has anyone used this Artery before? I am not sure whether to use Artery or redefine PLEXE (which is more popular).

Best regards,
Huy Nguyen.

Comment: Did you get a solution? I need to simulate an environment in the ETSI standard and I was not successful either.

Comment: Hello @dnat, I posted the answer. Please refer to that. thank you